# Swift how to resign first responder on all uiTextfield

Tags: swift, uitextfielddelegate

I would like to use resign the first responder on all `uitextfield`. I'm able to complete this by placing the `uitextfields` in an array but I wanted to avoid using the array. the resign should happen to all type of uiTextField how can this be done.

This works fine

```swift
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var textFieldtwo: UITextField!

        var textField = [UITextField]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.textField = [text,textFieldtwo]

            for item in textField {
                item.delegate = self
            }
        }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            print("text")

            for item in textField {
                item.resignFirstResponder()
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for textField in self.view.subviews where textField is UITextField {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

But if you just want to **dismiss the Keyboard** by pressing the `return` on the `keyboard` or tapping anywhere on the screen without using `touchesBegan`

You can try with this:

```
// For pressing return on the keyboard to dismiss keyboard
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    for textField in self.view.subviews where textField is UITextField {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

...

```
func hideKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

And add this to your `viewDidLoad`:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: please, what is purpose from resignFirstResponder() ?

Comment: You can read here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621097-resignfirstresponder

Answer (score 32):

A simpler approach would by to end editing on the UIView containing the UITextFields by saying:

```
view.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: "view.endEditing(true)" work great for touches began but it does not work for "textFieldShouldReturn"

Answer (score 32):

Or just use a more global approach. (Swift 3.0)

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIApplication.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil);
```

This will dismiss any active field as it resigns the current first responder.
Good luck coding!

Comment: Is this safe to be used, I mean, would Apple approve the app submitted to the app store with this code?

Answer (score 9):

Now In Swift 3, the easiest methods are

**Method 1:** 
 called when 'return' key pressed.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
 {
 textField1.resignFirstResponder()
 textField2.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }
```

**Method 2:**  called when 'return' key pressed.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
    {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true;
    }
```

**Method 3:** Global Method Write in view did load

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add this. Other wise its not work.

```
UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate
```

I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: when I use this it prevents any other touch events from firing.. great at dismissing keyboards but renders by view uneditable

Comment: @nbpeth yes I can understand your problem this happen due to In method 3 **UIView** is the parent of all other views.

Answer (score 1):

### resignFirstResponder with toolbars buttons Swift4 ##

You can try this : 
 1. *check the Textfield Delegate*
`class CoursesViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {`

2. *create a TextField var:*  `var currentTextField:UITextField!`
3. *create "done" & "cancel" buttons toolBar in your TextField*

   ```
   func addDoneCancel(_ textField : UITextField) {

       curentTextField = textField

       // ToolBar
       let toolBar = UIToolbar()
       toolBar.barStyle = .default
       toolBar.isTranslucent = true
       toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
       toolBar.sizeToFit()

       // Adding Button ToolBar
       let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(CoursesViewController.doneClick))
       let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
       let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(CoursesViewController.cancelClick))
       toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
       toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
       textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
   }
   ```

4.*actions of toolbar buttons*

```
@objc func doneClick(){
    curentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

@objc func cancelClick(){
    curentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

5.*UItextField delegate*

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    curentTextField = textField
    addDoneCancel(textField)
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {    
    //delegate method
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {  
    //delegate method
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   
    //delegate method
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4:**

In case you have IBOutlets:

```
_ = [textFiledOne, textFiledTwo, textFiledThree].map() { $0.resignFirstResponder() }
```